# Retirar extensões que não utilizo impactaria no desempenho da execução da página PHP

Tags: php, extensão

Instalei o PHP através do Web Platform e ele veio com várias extensões carregadas:

**php.ini**

```
[ExtensionList]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
```

Retirar extensões que não utilizo impactaria no desempenho da execução da página PHP?

Comment: Creio que são utilizadas somente quando solicitada pelo script, sendo assim, "acho" que naum...

Comment: Eu tenho o hábito de desativar tudo que não uso por uma série de outras razões, mas a performance não vai mudar. Sugeriria desativar tudo o que está "sobrando", desde amanha ou depois, quando você instalar alguma coisa que precise de algum deles, lembre-se que desativou.

Comment: Ao invés de especular, por que não medir o desempenho com as extensões presentes e ausentes, comparar os resultados e chegar em uma conclusão objetiva?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira como posso medir o desempenho?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apesar de concordar com os comentários e a [outra resposta do Brittz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141523/3635), ainda existem sim extensões que quando desabilitadas melhoram sim a performance do servidor, hoje é um tanto incomum mas antigamente os servidores Shared e VPS vinham como extensões como XDebug e/ou Xhprof habilitados.

Se você tem controle total sobre o teu servidor é preferível verificar todas extensões que são usadas para depurar e desligar elas.

Os testes a seguir foram feitos em:

- PHP 5.6 (x86_x64)
- Windows 8 64bit
- Apache 2.3.4

### Memória

Criei o seguinte arquivo `foo.php` e rodei via http (`http://localhost/foo.php`):

```
<?php

register_shutdown_function(function () {
    echo 'Pico de uso da memória: ', memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 'kb', PHP_EOL;
});
```

- Resultado xdebug **desligado**:

  > Pico de uso da memória: 217.15625kb
- Resultado xdebug **ligado**:

  > Pico de uso da memória: 234.6171875kb

A principio parece insignificante, mas isso é um resultado com um arquivo "vazio", se usar um framework como Laravel irá notar o impacto

- Laravel com xdebug desligado:

  > Pico de uso da memória: 7312.4921875kb
- Laravel com xdebug ligado:

  > Pico de uso da memória: 8377.90625kb

O pico poderia ter sido maior, mas esse exemplo é o Laravel "limpo"

### Requisições por segundo

Fiz o teste com o `foo.php` usando o ApacheBench

- Com Xdebug desligado o resultado foi ~3000.63 requisições por segundo, resposta completa:

  ```
  Server Software:        Apache/2.4.3
  Server Hostname:        localhost
  Server Port:            80

  Document Path:          /foo.php
  Document Length:        37 bytes

  Concurrency Level:      10
  Time taken for tests:   0.333 seconds
  Complete requests:      1000
  Failed requests:        0
  Write errors:           0
  Total transferred:      202000 bytes
  HTML transferred:       37000 bytes
  Requests per second:    3000.63 [#/sec] (mean)
  Time per request:       3.333 [ms] (mean)
  Time per request:       0.333 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
  Transfer rate:          591.92 [Kbytes/sec] received

  Connection Times (ms)
                min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
  Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       2
  Processing:     1    3   5.1      3     112
  Waiting:        0    3   5.0      2     110
  Total:          1    3   5.1      3     112

  Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
    50%      3
    66%      3
    75%      3
    80%      3
    90%      4
    95%      5
    98%      8
    99%     18
   100%    112 (longest request)
  executed: ab -n 1000 -c 10 "http://localhost/foo.php"
  ```
- Com Xdebug ligado foram ~1978.29 requisições por segundo:

  ```
  Server Software:        Apache/2.4.3
  Server Hostname:        localhost
  Server Port:            80

  Document Path:          /foo.php
  Document Length:        38 bytes

  Concurrency Level:      10
  Time taken for tests:   0.505 seconds
  Complete requests:      1000
  Failed requests:        0
  Write errors:           0
  Total transferred:      203000 bytes
  HTML transferred:       38000 bytes
  Requests per second:    1978.29 [#/sec] (mean)
  Time per request:       5.055 [ms] (mean)
  Time per request:       0.505 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
  Transfer rate:          392.18 [Kbytes/sec] received

  Connection Times (ms)
                min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
  Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       3
  Processing:     1    5   4.5      4      64
  Waiting:        1    4   4.5      4      63
  Total:          1    5   4.5      4      64

  Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
    50%      4
    66%      5
    75%      5
    80%      5
    90%      6
    95%      7
    98%     13
    99%     27
   100%     64 (longest request)
  executed: ab -n 1000 -c 10 "http://localhost/foo.php"
  ```

**Resumindo,** ou seja praticamente ~1000 requisições a menos em um segundo

Note que os testes foram feitos com XDebug em suas configurações minimas, se usar profile e outras coisas ainda pode consumir mais.

### Extensões que melhoram a performance

Sim existem, nenhuma linguagem no back-end vai conseguir atingir uma boa performance de verdade a não ser que ela seja "compilada" e/ou use estrutura de "Opcode", muitas linguagens de servidor tem algo como isto, mas o PHP <s>não tem</s> (não tinha), ao menos não habilitado por padrão.

- PHP 5.4 e mais antigos:

  Temos o [*XCache*](https://xcache.lighttpd.net), ele da uma pequena melhora no servidor, até aonde testei ele pode ser muito útil para frameworks mais pesados.

  Esta extensão não é mantida pela equipe do PHP, mas sim pela equipe do lighttPD, ou seja talvez tenha que instalar manualmente (e compilar).

  No entanto alguns servidores tem ela instalada já, só é necessário habilitar, mas se não tiver então terá que compilar diretamente no teu servidor e configurar, se não tiver esta opção então só solicitando para o suporte. Fora isto ela não requer configurar muita coisa, a não ser o `cacher` no php.ini:

  ```
  [xcache]
  xcache.cacher="On"
  ```
- PHP 5.4:

  Na versão 5.4 foi criado o [*Alternative PHP Cache (APC)*](https://pecl.php.net/package/APC), no entanto agora só pode ser instalado via PECL, ele demonstrou ter uma boa eficiência, todavia é complicado instalar em servidores de produção.
- PHP 5.5:

  A partir do 5.5 temos o [*Opcache (ou Zend Opcache)*](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php), apesar de só estar disponível nativamente no PHP 5.5 é possível instalar em versões mais antigas através do [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache) (5.2, 5.3 e 5.4), dos testes que realizei ele foi o mais eficiente.

Todos os 3 citados usam uma estrutura chamada Opcode, claro que cada a sua maneira, mas o uso deles todavia melhora significativamente a performance das execuções dos scripts.

Uso de memória com ZendOPcache do script `foo.php`:

> Pico de uso da memória: 206.4453125kb

Parece insignificante, mas se somar múltiplas requisições e o uso de um framework pesado irá notar uma boa diferença.

Veja a diferença do Laravel:

> Pico de uso da memória: 2308.3203125kb

Lembre-se que sem o ZendOPcache os consumo era de 7312.4921875kb

- 2308.3203125 é aproximadamente 2.25mb
- 7312.4921875 é aproximadamente 7.14mb

Ou seja uma economia de 4.89mb, se fizer 10 requisições ao mesmo tempo em um segundo será uma economia de 48.9mb. Isso ajuda a evitar que atinja o pico de memória do servidor.

Mas tenha em mente que é relativo, não adianta usar OPcache e:

- Escrever scripts ruins
- Fazer uma má estrutura do banco
- Inserir várias imagens na página, .js e .css sem necessidade

O OPCache não fará milagres, você tem que cuidar destes outros detalhes também, é **tudo relativo**.

Segue uma configuração básica do *OPcache* (necessita usar `zend_extension`):

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Se for Unix-like (Linux, Mac, BSD):

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=php_opcache.so
```

### Conclusão

Da sua lista nenhuma extensão irá afetar a performance, todavia talvez você não precise da extensão de mysqli e da pdo ao mesmo tempo, mas desligar não fará diferença nenhuma, se você vier a usar um script de terceiros que não use mysqli, mas sim pdo e outro script seu precise do mysqli então será melhor deixar ambos ligados.

A extensão de imap talvez você não use, mas se for adicionar um web-email, como squiremal ou roundcube será preciso esta extensão, as demais extensões são o minimo para se usar as funções básica de texto, xml, etc.

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
```

Eu pessoalmente deixaria todas listadas acima ligadas, menos a de SOAP (é que é um pouco incomum usar isto)

Comment: O SOAP é necessário para o NewRelic, salvo engano. Eu me recordo que quando instalei o New Relic começou a parecer nos logs erros com o SOAP, então tive que dar aquele velho `yum` para resolver. ;P

Comment: @Inkeliz entendo, eu não quis dizer desnecessário, só quis dizer que hoje em dia é incomum, já que temos outros tipo de webservices ou o processo é feito manualmente :)