# Hospedando sistema Laravel 5.3 em subdomínio

Tags: laravel-5.3

Boa tarde.
Estou com um problema para upar meu sistema criado com laravel 5.3 para a  hospedagem.

Criei uma pasta para o **Projeto** e coloquei os arquivos da pasta **public** para a public_html. Fiz os devidos redirecionamentos, porém estou com um erro *ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR*

Fiz algumas pesquisas, e vi alguns problemas relacionados a configuração do arquivo .htaccess, a versão do php tbm está ok.

O arquivo .htaccess esta da seguinte forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Será que alguém já passou por algo parecido e poderia me dar uma ajuda ?

Comment: Eu uso sempre esse, juliano... Sendo assim não faço ideia, gostava de ter ajudado. Experimenta algum destes links: https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=remove+public+laravel

Comment: @Miguel esse também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já tinha visto essa, também já tinha dado +1. Boa resposta, acho que isso resolve o pronlema do AP

Answer (score 2):

Não parece um erro mod_rewrite, se fosse seria por não ter ativo, mas existe uma `if`.

Primeiro para ter certeza do problema, procure o log de erros do PHP (é um arquivo .txt, esta configurado no php.ini)

Note que o Laravel 5.3 conforme a documentação mostra https://laravel.com/docs/5.3#server-requirements precisa:

- PHP 5.6.4 ou maior
- Extensão OpenSSL para PHP
- Extensão PDO para PHP
- Extensão Mbstring para PHP
- Extensão Tokenizer para PHP
- Extensão XML para PHP

Se estiver em uma versão **inferior** ao 5.6.4 este erro vai ocorrer com certeza. Não ter as extensões ativas também causa o erro as vezes, note que o erro 500 é exibido pois o PHP está em modo de produção e por isso não apresenta detalhes do erro, o melhor é olhar o log.

Todas extensões podem ser habilitadas no php.ini, se for hospedagem Like-unix:

```
extension=openssl.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=tokenizer.so
```

O XML eu creio que seja compilado junto com o PHP, então se não tiver (o que acho impossível) será meio difícil resolver.

> **Nota:** o exemplo do PDO é para mysql, se for outro banco veja http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Se for Windows-server:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_tokenizer.dll
```

E também precisa ter o `mod_rewrite` habilitado, mas esse geralmente não causa erro 500.

Para saber aonde está o log, você pode criar um arquivo chamado `teste.php` (delete depois) e colocar algo como:

```
<?php
echo 'Log:';
var_dump(ini_get('error_log'));
```

Então executar ele assim: `http://meusite.com/teste.php`, se aparecer `NULL` é porque não tem log configurado, então terá que configurar e o acesso ao PHP.INI depende muito de como o servidor libera, então terá que conversar com o suporte da hospedagem.

### Movendo para public_html

Como expliquei aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91799/3635, note também que a estrutura de pastas deve ficar assim:

```
/home/user/
   |--- /access-logs     (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
   |--- /etc             (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
   |--- /public_ftp      (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
   |--- /tmp             (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
   |--- /public_html     (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
          |--- index.php (arquivo da pasta /public)
          |--- .htaccess (arquivo da pasta /public)
   |--- /app             (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
   |--- /bootstrap       (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
   |--- /config          (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
   |--- /database        (pasta do seu projeto laravel)
```

Comment: Alterei a versão do PHP do servidor para a 7.0 e agora esta dando erro:
 Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 411041792) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/usuario/sistema/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 1

Comment: @JulianoMoura qual a configuração no php.ini de memoria do teu php7? Veja o `memory_limit=`

Comment: como não localizei nenhum arquivo php.ini no servidor eu criei um. Coloquei memory_limit para 2048

Comment: @JulianoMoura criou aonde? Isso não faz muito sentido e creio que não funcione. Tem que editar o php.ini ou usar php_mod (algumas hospedagens oferecem isso como alternativa) ou phprc, e o memory limit tem que ter um M no final, por exemplo `memory_limit=32M`. **Note:** cada requisição do Laravel gasta 7Mb de memoria do servidor (o minimo, o maximo não da para afirmar), então recomendo no minimo usar `32M`, isso é claro que vai depender da velocidade do teu servidor, recomendo também que ative o Opcache: recomendo que leia isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152472/3635

Comment: Segui este tutorial para criar o php.ini
https://faq.hostgator.com.br/content/70/321/pt-br/configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-php-com-o-arquivo-phpini.html

Comment: @JulianoMoura blz, cria um arquivo chamado `teste.php` na public_html e coloca isso `<?php var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));` e me diga o que retorna.

Comment: string(4) "256M"

Comment: @JulianoMoura mas o laravel ainda apresenta algum erro?

Comment: continua aparecendo o erro  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /home/calango3/sistema/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 35

quando mudo o memory_limit os bytes mudam, mas ainda premanece o erro

Comment: @JulianoMoura vc sabe que depois de editar o php.ini é necessário reiniciar a máquina? Se não tiver feito por favor reinicie ela.

Comment: entrei em contato com o suporte da hostgator e me informaram que o servidor compartilhado tem 256mb de memoria. Recomendou otimizar o sistema e tentar novamente.

Vou instalar o laravel no servidor e criar uma aplicação para verificar se vai funcionar.

Assim que tiver feito dou um feedback

Comment: @JulianoMoura não se esqueça de configurar o Opcache, tenho quase certeza que esse erro não é por falta de memoria e sim alguma falha na sua instalação do laravel, tipo uma extensão não habilitada.

Answer (score 1):

Dando um retorno sobre o problema ...

segui a dica do suporte da hostgator e utilizei este tutorial para instalar o laravel no servidor via composer:

http://forum.hostgator.com.br/topic/1297-instalando-laravel/

com o tutorial consegui instalar o laravel, criei um projeto novo e substitui os arquivos para o meu projeto que estava tentando upar para o servidor.
Tudo funcionando agora !

Obrigado Guilherme Nascimento pela ajuda.