# Como saber a quantidade de memória utilizada pela minha aplicação em PHP?

Tags: php, memória, debug

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de saber o quanto a minha aplicação PHP está consumindo de memória.

Por exemplo: Quero saber, no final da execução do script, quanto o PHP gastou no processo de execução de uma determinado script.

Existe alguma função em PHP que eu possa fazer essa verificação?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre “memory_get_usage” e “memory_get_peak_usage”?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178312/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-memory-get-usage-e-memory-get-peak-usage)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como já foi citado, [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) captura o gasto de memória no momento. No entanto, existe outra função, o [`memory_get_peak_usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php), que pega o pico de memória máximo registrado.

> **Nota:** tanto [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) quanto [`memory_get_peak_usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) só obtém o resultado definido pelo [**`emalloc()`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/internals2.memory.management.php) é retornado.

Então as diferenças são:

- [**memory_get_usage**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) retorna o gasto de memoria atual aproximado, por exemplo:

  ```
  <?php

  echo round(memory_get_usage() / 1024, 4), 'Kb', PHP_EOL; // 219.2656Kb

  $a = str_repeat("Hello", 4242);

  echo round(memory_get_usage() / 1024, 4), 'Kb', PHP_EOL; // 240.1797Kb

  unset($a);

  echo round(memory_get_usage() / 1024, 4), 'Kb', PHP_EOL; // 219.3125Kb
  ```

  Os valores variam conforme o sistema e versão usada do PHP, também varia se estiver usando extensões como `Opcache` ou `XCache`
- [**memory_get_peak_usage**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) retorna o pico de memória gasto até o momento, então

  ```
  <?php

  echo round(memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 4), 'Kb', PHP_EOL; // 222.8906Kb

  $a = str_repeat("Hello", 4242);

  echo round(memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 4), 'Kb', PHP_EOL; // 241.7422Kb

  unset($a);

  echo round(memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 4), 'Kb', PHP_EOL; // 241.8047Kb
  ```

  Veja que os números permanecem e sempre aumentam.

### Testando no final do script

Existe uma função chamada [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.register-shutdown-function.php) que é executado ao final do script, seria como um "`__destruct` global", neste momento é interessante fazer a checagem do pico de memória, assim:

```
<?php

register_shutdown_function(function() {
    echo PHP_EOL, round(memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 4), 'Kb';
});

$a = str_repeat("Hello", 4242);

unset($a);
```

Assim sempre que o script maior for terminado (os que são incluídos não disparam esta função a não ser que exista um `exit;` ou `die('foo');`) e irá adicionar ao fim do output/saída/corpo do documento o resultado de quanto foi gasto.

> Nota: `register_shutdown_function` pode ser adicionado a qualquer momento antes do *shutdown*

### Aqui sobre extensões

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152472/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635

Comment: Guilherme podes colar esta resposta aqui também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178312/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-memory-get-usage-e-memory-get-peak-usage :P

Comment: @Miguel acho que a outra é dup desta no momento que eu respondi, não acho legal replicar a resposta

Comment: Não é duplicada. As respostas podem ser duplicadas, a pergunta não. De qualquer forma, seria legal se na outra pergunta detalhassem mais (se tiver o que detalhar). Assim, aqui ficaria com a explicação superficial, e lá, com a profunda.

Comment: Guilherme, estava na brincadeira. Com certeza que não ias fazer isso

Answer (score 3):

A função [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) retorna o número de bytes alocados para o script.

Um exemplo retirado da documentação do PHP:

```php
// É apenas um exemplo os números serão diferentes dependendo do sistema
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 36640

$a = str_repeat("Hello", 4242);

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 57960

unset($a);

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 36744
```

Answer (score 3):

[memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php):

`memory_get_usage()` retorna a quantidade de memória em bytes que está a ser usada pelo teu script php.

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/C0kQjk):

```
echo memory_get_usage(); // 112388 (bytes)
```

Caso coloques o argumento como `true` (`memory_get_usage(true)`), é te retornado o total de memória reservada no sistema para o teu script php:

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/4vTt8m), com entrada de argumento como `true`:

```
echo memory_get_usage(true); // 262144 (bytes)
```

Ou seja se quiseres a memória real que o sistema está a usar deves fazer como na ultima demonstração em cima, `memory_get_usage(true)`

E se quiseres saber a memoria real que o teu script consumiu (dentro da memória reservada, obviamente) usa o primeiro exemplo.

Comment: A pergunta se refere a medir a quantidade de memória usada em um script específico. Dessa maneira a uso do argumento `real_usage` não convém neste caso.

Comment: @fernandosavio, nesse caso podes usar o meu primeiro exemplo, sem `true`, isso foi para complementar a resposta esclarencendo o que a função consegue fazer

Comment: @fernandosavio quando o PHP é incluido em outro todos somam junto ao  [`emalloc()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/internals2.memory.management.php) (leia sobre a API), ou seja pode ser até que consiga pegar por script, mas tera que aplicar um a uma o que poderia ser feito no momento do incluide e de qualquer forma a interpretação do script ocorre primeiro que a execução e uma chamada de uma função em um script diferente não define o peso de onde foi declarado, mas do consumo de execução, ao meu ver a resposta do Miguel esta correta.

Comment: De maneira nenhuma achei que a resposta está incorreta. Pra ser sincero acho mais correta que a minha. Só levantei a questão mais pela pergunta mesmo, pois não adicionei detalhes sobre o argumento da função para que se encaixe melhor na resposta dele.
Mesmo assim obrigado por explicar sobre o `emalloc()`.