# Qual é a diferença entre "memory_get_usage" e "memory_get_peak_usage"?

Tags: php

Qual é a diferença entre as funções `memory_get_usage` e `memory_get_peak_usage`?

As duas fazem a mesma coisa ou existe alguma diferença entre elas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`memory_get_usage` é a quantidade de memória sendo utilizada naquele momento.

`memory_get_peak_usage` é a quantidade de memória máxima atingida durante toda a execução do script.

Comment: parece até que copiei o formato, mas já tava assim mesmo..hehe +1

Answer (score 4):

[`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.memory-get-usage.php): Retorna a quantidade de memória alocada para PHP.

[`memory_get_peak_usage`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php): Retorna o pico de memória alocado pelo PHP.

E a diretiva :

[`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit): Diretiva do `php.ini` que define a quantidade máxima de memória em bytes que um script está permitido alocar.