# PHP 7.1 Como desabilitar recursos de BD não usados?

Tags: php

No php 7.1 a configuração do php.ini (original da Locaweb) contém vários comandos de BD que não uso.

Eu só uso o Mysql com PDO.

**O que pode ser desativado no php.ini e como faze-lo?**

Abaixo o php.ini só com as linhas referentes a BDs.

```
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mSQL]
msql.allow_persistent = On
msql.max_persistent = -1
msql.max_links = -1

[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase]
sybase.allow_persistent = On
sybase.max_persistent = -1
sybase.max_links = -1
sybase.min_error_severity = 10
sybase.min_message_severity = 10
sybase.compatability_mode = Off

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[Informix]
ifx.default_host =
ifx.default_user =
ifx.default_password =
ifx.allow_persistent = On
ifx.max_persistent = -1
ifx.max_links = -1
ifx.textasvarchar = 0
ifx.byteasvarchar = 0
ifx.charasvarchar = 0
ifx.blobinfile = 0
ifx.nullformat = 0

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário remover os comandos, basta desabilitar os add-ons que não irá usar, eu fiz uma explicação breve sobre isto em:

- [Retirar extensões que não utilizo impactaria no desempenho da execução da página PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152472/3635)

Então supondo que vá usar somente PDO com Mysql e não vai usar mysqli, você poderia comentar as linhas assim usando `;` no php.ini:

Se for Windows Server (ou Windows normal):

```
;extension=php_mongo.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oauth.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
```

Se for Unix-like:

```
;extension=mongo.so
;extension=mysqli.so
;extension=oauth.so
;extension=oci8.so
;extension=oci8_11g.so
extension=openssl.so
;extension=pdo_firebird.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
;extension=pdo_oci.so
;extension=pdo_odbc.so
;extension=pdo_pgsql.so
;extension=pdo_sqlite.so
;extension=pgsql.so
;extension=pspell.so
```

Se for PHP7.2:

```
;extension=mongo
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oauth
;extension=oci8
;extension=oci8_11g
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=pspell
```

**Note** que as linhas com `;` serão ignoradas quando você reiniciar o Apache (wamp, xampp, easyphp) ou Ngnix, somente as linhas sem irão carregar as **extensões php**

> **Nota:** os exemplos acima foram do meu PHP que é o 5.4 e o 7.2, são somente exemplos

Comment: Li seu outro post e conclui que inibir não melhora na performance. certo?

Comment: E qto a segurança? Não deixa caminhos abertos? A sua orientação acima vale para php 7.1 tb? obrigado !!

Comment: @Geo sim, é pouca coisa para alguns e para outros muita coisa, depende da extensão que você quer desabilitar, no geral o legal é remover o que não vai usar. Isto não tem qualquer relação com segurança ou falhas, segurança é outro problema, que geralmente esta nos seus .php que você mesmo escreveu. Sim vale para qualquer versão do php, mas é apenas exemplo, você deve analisar o seu proprio php.ini e ver o que não vai usar ;)

Comment: No meu php.ini não tem nenhuma linha com extension= , procurei agora. Creio que a inibição deve ser feita no meu exemplo acima. Vc pode me orientar? obrigado

Comment: @Geo executa em um script .php o `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` é possivel que você esteja usando `.ini`s complementares

Comment: Fiquei confuso, abri o phpinfo e só mostra o mysqli (nem o mysql que uso normal/ e os outros do php.ini aparecem) a versão é php 7.1.7. É normal?

Comment: Verifica no `phpinfo` o caminho do seu `php.ini`. Talvez esteja alterando o arquivo incorreto. Ah, e não se esquece de reiniciar o `php` para surtir efeitos.

Comment: O php.ini está na raiz e igual ao mostrado no info. Inclusive para exibi-lo eu desbloqueio no ini o disable_functions que tem outros tb listados. E ainda desbloquei tudo no ini. Mas continua igual. Pode ser coisa da Locaweb? é hospedagem compartilhada.

Comment: @Geo pode sim, geralmente o locaweb usa linux, então não tem todas porque em linux vc instala via repositório, já em windows vc baixa tudo de uma vez.